# adding x and y Scrollbar to a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

Creating a program that will place an image onto a canvas. I want to add an X-axis, and Y-axis scrollbar onto the canvas, but I am not sure how to.

I would normally use a Frame, but the program I'm working on is using tkinter.Toplevel instead of using a Frame.

```
#----- Imports ---------------------
import os
import os.path
import sys

import tkinter
tk = tkinter
from tkinter import font

#----- Set flag for JPEG support ---
noJPEG = False
try:
    from PIL import Image
    Pimg = Image
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    Pdraw = ImageDraw.Draw
    from PIL import ImageTk
    Pimgtk = ImageTk
except ImportError:
    noJPEG = True
#

#------------------------------------
# Create an invisible global parent window to hold all children.
# Facilitates easy closing of all windows by a mouse click.
_root = tk.Tk()
_root.withdraw()
#


#------------------------------------
# A writeable window for holding an image.
#
class ImageView(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, image, title=''):
        master = tk.Toplevel(_root)
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master,
                           width = 600, height = 500,
                           scrollregion=(0,0, image.getWidth(),
                                         image.getHeight()))

        # Define class fields
        ## Image properties
        self.master.title(title)
        self.pack()
        master.resizable(0,0)
        self.foreground = "black"
        self.image = image
        self.height = image.getHeight()
        self.width = image.getWidth()
        # for later
        #self.customFont = font.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

        ## Actionable items
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.mouseFxn = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.onClick)  #bind action to button1 click
        self.tags = None

        _root.update()  #redraw global window
```

Comment: Why don't you just put a Frame in your Toplevel window? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31763876/4014959) will help.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I am not quite following.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you put a Frame into the Toplevel window and put a Canvas and Scrollbars into that Frame.

Comment: Could you help get me started? I'm looking up "how to put Frame into Toplevel window", but I'm not getting a lot of results.

Comment: A Toplevel widget is simply a container for other widgets, much like a Frame widget is. So if you know how to put widgets in a Frame then you already know how to put widgets in a Toplevel.

Comment: There's no reason to put a frame in a toplevel window just to get scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about using a `Toplevel` rather than a `Frame`. You attach a scrollbar the way you do it for any scrollable widget in any container.

I've never seen a widget create it's own parent. That's quite unusual, though it really doesn't change anything. Just add the scrollbars inside the toplevel.

You might want to switch to `grid` instead of `pack` since that makes it a bit easier to get the scrollbars to line up properly. You just need to remove the call to `self.pack()`, and add something like this to your code:

```
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=self.yview)
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient="horizontal", command=self.xview)
self.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Bryan Oakley! I've been struggling for quite awhile on how to solve this. I can't wait to show my instructor this!